# How to get the most profitable currency from a JSON?

Tags: json, bash, curl, max, jq

I'm trying to write a bash script that can adjust to the most profitable cryptocurrency to mine and change what is being mined on the fly.

I have used `curl` to grab API information from http://whattomine.com/coins.json using `curl` script:

```
curl whattomine.com/coins.json -O | > coins.json
```

Sample API:

```
{"coins":{"Nicehash-Ethash":{"id":15,"tag":"NICEHASH","algorithm":"Ethash","block_time":1,"block_reward":1,"block_reward24":1,"last_block":0,"difficulty":1,"difficulty24":1,"nethash":5595177528830,"exchange_rate":0.0084,"exchange_rate24":0.0086,"exchange_rate_vol":38.522578574534,"exchange_rate_curr":"BTC","market_cap":"$0.00","estimated_rewards":"0.00071","estimated_rewards24":"0.00072","btc_revenue":"0.0007056","btc_revenue24":"0.0007224","profitability":95,"profitability24":101,"lagging":false,"timestamp":1518385271},"EthereumClassic":{"id":162,"tag":"ETC","algorithm":"Ethash","block_time":"14.5606","block_reward":3.88,"block_reward24":3.88000000000005,"last_block":5372259,"difficulty":119798042603096.0,"difficulty24":118354683854950.0,"nethash":8227548494093,"exchange_rate":0.003034,"exchange_rate24":0.00285318393234672,"exchange_rate_vol":2318.70107084,"exchange_rate_curr":"BTC","market_cap":"$2,525,050,483.01","estimated_rewards":"0.23506","estimated_rewards24":"0.23792","btc_revenue":"0.00071316","btc_revenue24":"0.00072186","profitability":96,"profitability24":101,"lagging":false,"timestamp":1518385186},"Ethereum":{"id":151,"tag":"ETH","algorithm":"Ethash","block_time":"14.529","block_reward":2.91,"block_reward24":2.91000000000001,"last_block":5073173,"difficulty":2.86396845523669e+15,"difficulty24":2.96145362923571e+15,"nethash":197120824229932,"exchange_rate":0.100691,"exchange_rate24":0.100200274841438,"exchange_rate_vol":12443.48347244,"exchange_rate_curr":"BTC","market_cap":"$81,928,528,426.15","estimated_rewards":"0.00737","estimated_rewards24":"0.00713","btc_revenue":"0.00074252","btc_revenue24":"0.00071808","profitability":100,"profitability24":100,"lagging":false,"timestamp":1518385171},"Expanse":{"id":154,"tag":"EXP","algorithm":"Ethash","block_time":"45.0","block_reward":4.0,"block_reward24":4.0,"last_block":975425,"difficulty":13101309242779.0,"difficulty24":14838722424377.6,"nethash":291140205395,"exchange_rate":0.00033176,"exchange_rate24":0.000334064524312897,"exchange_rate_vol":10.94411548,"exchange_rate_curr":"BTC","market_cap":"$21,877,350.59","estimated_rewards":"2.2152","estimated_rewards24":"1.9559","btc_revenue":"0.00073491","btc_revenue24":"0.00064889","profitability":99,"profitability24":90,"lagging":false,"timestamp":1518383559},"Pirl":{"id":211,"tag":"PIRL","algorithm":"Ethash","block_time":"14.0","block_reward":10.0,"block_reward24":10.0,"last_block":825434,"difficulty":16734197347723.0,"difficulty24":16762811072321.5,"nethash":1195299810551,"exchange_rate":0.00014626,"exchange_rate24":0.000155109957716702,"exchange_rate_vol":12.9604288790783,"exchange_rate_curr":"BTC","market_cap":"$12,081,862.82","estimated_rewards":"4.33668","estimated_rewards24":"4.32928","btc_revenue":"0.00063428","btc_revenue24":"0.0006332","profitability":85,"profitability24":88,"lagging":false,"timestamp":1518385184},"Musicoin":{"id":178,"tag":"MUSIC","algorithm":"Ethash","block_time":"14.0","block_reward":246.2,"block_reward24":246.199999999998,"last_block":1953827,"difficulty":6613543703874.0,"difficulty24":6686438484420.37,"nethash":472395978848,"exchange_rate":2.34e-06,"exchange_rate24":2.29601694915254e-06,"exchange_rate_vol":17.78104309,"exchange_rate_curr":"BTC","market_cap":"$11,918,018.41","estimated_rewards":"270.12802","estimated_rewards24":"267.18363","btc_revenue":"0.0006321","btc_revenue24":"0.00062521","profitability":85,"profitability24":87,"lagging":false,"timestamp":1518385185},"Ellaism":{"id":221,"tag":"ELLA","algorithm":"Ethash","block_time":"14.0","block_reward":4.91,"block_reward24":4.91000000000001,"last_block":945964,"difficulty":4376186239122.0,"difficulty24":4319302576114.62,"nethash":312584731365,"exchange_rate":7.501e-05,"exchange_rate24":7.6147420718816e-05,"exchange_rate_vol":1.27998339143897,"exchange_rate_curr":"BTC","market_cap":"$2,958,733.31","estimated_rewards":"8.14071","estimated_rewards24":"8.24789","btc_revenue":"0.00061063","btc_revenue24":"0.00061867","profitability":82,"profitability24":86,"lagging":false,"timestamp":1518385172}
```

I would like to use the `profitability24` field.

Now that I have a json with the information I need I am having a lot of problems figuring out how to grab the most profitable currency (it's always the first in the json). My plan was to use jq but I'm open to ideas. My next step is to variablize the most profitable currency and then script out the proper command for the miner to start mining that currency.

Comment: Including a brief clip of the data structure would prevent users from having to click links. You should also include your code as text, not an image.

Comment: Im somewhat new so bear with me. I made requested changes.

Comment: a pipe (`|`) is one kind of redirection, while `>` is another redirection of output. But  you're using the `-O` option, so you should only need `curl -O whattomine.com/coins.json` to save the file to your local directory. The answers below look for the `jq` portion of your problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Under the assumption that your data structure is something like this:

```
$ cat test.json
{"coins" : { "coin1": { "id": 4,  "profitability24": 3 },
             "coin2": { "id": 5, "profitability24": 2 },
             "coin3": { "id": 6, "profitability24": 1 } } }
```

And you want to extract the max of 'profitability24, I would just filter out the dictionaries into a list, and then pipe that to `max_by` (did you read [the jq docs](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/)?):

```
$ cat test.json | jq '[.coins[]]|max_by(.profitability24)'
{
   "id": 4,
   "profitability24": 3
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you indicate that the item you want is "always the first", you could simply write:

```
first(.coins[])
```

If you want to ensure you always select one of the maximal objects, you could write:

```
[.coins[]] | max_by(.profitability24)
```

(For the sample data, these two approaches give different answers, as there are two maximal objects.)

If you want *all* maximal objects, then one approach would be to define and use `maximals_by(s; f)` as follows:

```
# Emit a stream of the maximal entities in the stream, s:
def maximals_by(s; f):
  reduce s as $x ({v:null, a:[]}; 
    ($x|f) as $y
    | if $y == .v then .a += [$x] elif $y > .v then {v:$y, a: [$x]} else . end)
  | .a[];


maximals_by(.coins[]; .profitability24)
```

With the given data, the last approach yields the two maximal items:

```
{
  "id": 15,
  "tag": "NICEHASH",
  "algorithm": "Ethash",
  "block_time": 1,
  "block_reward": 1,
  "block_reward24": 1,
  "last_block": 0,
  "difficulty": 1,
  "difficulty24": 1,
  "nethash": 5595177528830,
  "exchange_rate": 0.0084,
  "exchange_rate24": 0.0086,
  "exchange_rate_vol": 38.522578574534,
  "exchange_rate_curr": "BTC",
  "market_cap": "$0.00",
  "estimated_rewards": "0.00071",
  "estimated_rewards24": "0.00072",
  "btc_revenue": "0.0007056",
  "btc_revenue24": "0.0007224",
  "profitability": 95,
  "profitability24": 101,
  "lagging": false,
  "timestamp": 1518385271
}
{
  "id": 162,
  "tag": "ETC",
  "algorithm": "Ethash",
  "block_time": "14.5606",
  "block_reward": 3.88,
  "block_reward24": 3.88000000000005,
  "last_block": 5372259,
  "difficulty": 119798042603096,
  "difficulty24": 118354683854950,
  "nethash": 8227548494093,
  "exchange_rate": 0.003034,
  "exchange_rate24": 0.00285318393234672,
  "exchange_rate_vol": 2318.70107084,
  "exchange_rate_curr": "BTC",
  "market_cap": "$2,525,050,483.01",
  "estimated_rewards": "0.23506",
  "estimated_rewards24": "0.23792",
  "btc_revenue": "0.00071316",
  "btc_revenue24": "0.00072186",
  "profitability": 96,
  "profitability24": 101,
  "lagging": false,
  "timestamp": 1518385186
}
```